# Python unittest not recognizing tests

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm trying to learn how to use the `unittest` framework in python. I keep getting the message below when I run my file containing the tests.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

I've searched here and elsewhere and can't figure out why it is not recognizing the tests. Each test starts with `test` and the other portions of the `unittest` seem to match what the documentation requires.

Here is the text of the script:

```
import unittest
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Activity(object):
    'Holds detail information on a activity'
    def __init__(self, location, activity_name, activity_id, start_date, end_date):
        self.activity_name = activity_name
        self.activity_id = activity_id
        self.start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
        self.end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
        self.location = location

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

class TestActivity(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.activity = Activity('UVU', 'OpenWest', 'Beginning Python'
                            , '00000', '12/1/2013', '12/30/3013')

    def test_activity_creation(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.activity.location, 'UVU')
        self.assertEqual(self.activity.activity_name, 'OpenWest')
        self.assertEqual(self.activity.activity_id, '00000')
        self.assertEqual(self.activity.start_date, datetime.strptime('12/1/2013', '%m/%d/%Y').date())
        self.assertEqual(self.activity.start_date, datetime.strptime('12/30/2013', '%m/%d/%Y').date())

    def test1(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,1)

    def tearDown(self):
        del self.activity
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What does your project structure look like and how are you running your tests? Personally, I use nosetests for test discovery.

Comment: It's a pretty small project, just a few scripts. I'm very new to unit testing (and programming in general), so I'm using this small project to learn unit tests and other various topics. I'll take a look at nosetests as well. Thank you. You can see the project at github.com/srdone/ConsecutiveTime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

To the end of the script, then it will work.

## Update

Here is my speculation: when you called `unittest.main()` in the middle of the script, your test class has not been defined yet, thus `unittest` did not pick up any tests. By moving the `unittest.main()` to the end, or more precisely--after your define your test class, you make sure that `unittest` **sees** those tests.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! So do you have to put it at the end because otherwise the test cases aren't loaded?

Comment: Python modules are executed top->down when imported/ran. So, in this case at the time that unittest.main() was ran. There was exactly 0 test cases in the namespace that it was looking in. Had you moved it to the bottom or to another file that imported it (after the import of course) then it would do the same thing as suggested in this answer. So @haivu, I agree with your speculation.

Answer (score 0):

1. `main()` isn't needed.
2. Django is picky on where the tests are.  If your app is in `myapp/`, tests should be in `myapp/tests.py` as I recall.

Example:

```
./manage.py test
```

or
    ./manage.py test -v2 myapp

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution using `python3.9`. The trick was to **prefix the test file with `test`, all lower case.** (I followed it with an underscore for visual separation, but it's not required.)

Directory structure:

```
Some-Project
└── server
    └── api-devops
        └── scripts
            └── crash_monitoring
                ├── CrashDump.py
                ├── test_CrashDump.py
                ├── env
                └── requirements.txt
```

Contents of `test_CrashDump.py`:

```
import unittest


class CrashDumpTest(unittest.TestCase):  # The class name is irrelevant. It does not need to contain the word 'test'.

    def test_something(self):  # Like the filename, the function name must begin with 'test'
        self.assertTrue(True)
```

As @johntellsall says, `main()` isn't needed.

Command to run from root directory, `Some-Project`:

```
(env) Some-Project cameronhudson$ python3 -m unittest discover -s ./server/api-devops/scripts/crash_monitoring
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Command to run from the directory containing the tests, `crash_monitoring`:

```
(env) crash_monitoring cameronhudson$ python3 -m unittest
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```